# React Native Webview onShouldStartLoadWithRequest does not detect history.push()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm trying to make my React web application native using React Native Webview. In order to implement native social oauth, I made a screen that requires users sign in and after the users sign in, a webView with my web application url is rendered:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the app has valid tokens
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn,
        login: () => setIsLoggedIn(true),
        logout: () => setIsLoggedIn(false),
      }}>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <MyWebView />
        </SafeAreaView>
      ) : (
        <LoginScreen />
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

If users navigate to a page in my domain, my app renders it in `MyWebView`, otherwise my app opens the os browser with the external url. Also, I want my app to confirm and set `isLoggedIn` to `false` so that the app stops rendering `MyWebView` and goes back to `LoginScreen`, if users try to navigate to `${BASE_URL}/logout`, :

```js
const MyWebView = () => {
  const { logout: appLogout } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const askForLogout = () => {
    const title = 'Logout';
    const message = 'Do you want to sign out?';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Alert.alert(
        title,
        message,
        [
          { text: 'cancel', onPress: () => resolve(false) },
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => resolve(true) },
        ],
        { cancelable: false },
      );
      reject('Error');
    });
  };

  const onLogout = async () => {
    try {
      const shouldLogout = await askForLogout();
      if (!shouldLogout) {
        return;
      }
      await logout(); // This expires tokens
      appLogout();
    } catch (e) {
      alertError();
    }
  };

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: BASE_URL }}
      sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      renderLoading={() => <ActivityIndicator />}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={navState => {
        const { url } = navState;
        if (url.startsWith(BASE_URL)) {
          if (url.includes('/logout')) {
            onLogout();
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        } else {
          // External Links
          Linking.openURL(url);
          return false;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default MyWebView;
```

The problem is, `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` sometimes (almost always) does not detect navigations using `history.push(path)` so my app cannot detect whether users navigate to `/logout` and call the logout function. `onNavigationStateChange` can detect `history.push(path)`, but with `onNavigationStateChange` my app cannot stops external links from being rendered in `MyWebView` (This is bad because some external links use insecure HTTP, causing `NSURLErrorDomain`)

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!